# Why doesn't this BroadcastReceiver work?

Tags: java, android

I want to make a `BroadcastReceiver` so that I get notified when the screen is turned off and I then turn that on again, but it does not do anything, what is the problem?

```
public class SplashScreen extends SherlockActivity {
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE))
                    .newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
            screenLock.acquire();

        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.sensounlock.R.layout.rotation);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(rec, filter);
}
```

Comment: have you registered it in your manifest ?

Comment: @twntee not needed, I want to register that by code

Answer (score 0):

move your

```
BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE))
                    .newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
            screenLock.acquire();

        }

    }
};
```

under your oncreate

```
public class SplashScreen extends SherlockActivity {
PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.sensounlock.R.layout.rotation);

BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            WakeLock screenLock = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE))
                    .newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
                            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
            screenLock.acquire();

        }

    }
};
        registerReceiver(rec, new IntentFilter("package.name.xx"));
        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                "package.name.xx"), 0);
}
```

Comment: and on stop you can stop it by     unregisterReceiver(xxx);

Comment: and package.name.xx is the complete name of my package, e.g. com.example ?

Comment: yup it's the complete package name